# How to indicate database transaction commit in sequence diagram

Tags: diagram, sequence-diagram

I am not much sure this question is suit for SF. if not im sorry. my question is how could i draw the database transaction commit  in the sequence diagram.

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have an object representing the transaction or the database.

Then you could represent it with a message labeled as "commit" from your business object to the transaction/database object.

For example (can't post image because of my reputation):

```
 +-----------------+
 | Business Object |
 +-----------------+
         |
         | start transaction        +----------------------+
         +------------------------> | Database Transaction |
         |                          +----------------------+
         |                                    |
         | do lots of things                  |
         +----------------------------------->|
         |                                    |
         | commit                             |
         +----------------------------------->|
```